# Find volume on a shape with base of an ellipse

Tags: calculus, volume

I have an ellipse with area $\pi ab$ $a = 6$, $b = 4$ these are the axis lengths. I am suppose to compute the volume of a cone of height 12.

I tried many solutions but none of them worked and I don't know why. I would type them up but I doubt much could be learned. Basically I have been trying to use the fact that $\pi ab$ is the area that I can find $a$ or $b$ and then that ratio is my radius at any point. This doesn't really work though and I don't know why.

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you looked at [the section **Volume** in Wikipedia article **Cone**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone#Volume)?

Comment: No but I think I will be able to in four years of intensive math study.

Comment: What solutions have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume the cone is vertical, its axis is the $z$-axis and its base is an
ellipse on the $xy$-plane, centered at $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$, with semi-major
axis $a$ and semi-minor axis $b$. The equation of the base is thus

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1,\qquad z=0.$$

Let $h$ be the height of the cone. The
cone cross section at height $z$ is an ellipse with semi-major axis $$x_1=a\left( 1-\frac{z}{h}\right) $$ and semi-minor axis $$x_2=b\left( 1-\frac{z}{h}\right) $$ by similarity of (right) triangles, as shown in the following sketch:

[image]

The equation of the boundary of this cross section is

$$\frac{x^2}{x_1^2}+\frac{y^2}{x_2^2}=1,\qquad z=z.$$

> Basically I have been trying to use the fact that $\pi ab$ is the area

The area $A(z)$ of this cross section is thus
$$
\begin{equation*}
A(z)=\pi x_1 x_2=\pi ab\left( 1-\frac{z}{h}\right) ^{2}.
\end{equation*}
$$

The volume is the integral of the area $A(z)$ from $z=0$ to $z=h$

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
V &=&\int_{0}^{h}A(z)\, dz=\int_{0}^{h}\pi ab\left( 1-\frac{z}{h}\right) ^{2}dz
\\
&=&\pi ab\int_{0}^{h}\left( 1-2\frac{z}{h}+\frac{z^{2}}{h^{2}}\right) dz
\\
&=&\pi ab\left( h-h+\frac{h}{3}\right) =\frac{h}{3}\pi ab,
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
i.e. 
$$V=\frac{1}{3}A_{\text{base}}\times \text{height},$$

as expected. For $a=6,b=4,h=12$, we have:
$$
\begin{equation*}
V=\frac{h}{3}\pi ab=96\pi.
\end{equation*}
$$

Comment: I don't follow your area formula. The cross section is an ellipse is it not?

Comment: @user84004 Yes, it is an ellipse but with semi-major axis $x_1$ and semi-minor axis $x_2$. For $z=0$ the cross section is just the base, an ellipse with semi-major axis $a$ and semi-minor axis $b$. For $z$ variable $x_1$ and $x_2$ are functions of $z$ as written above: $$x_1=a\left( 1-\frac{z}{h}\right) $$ and  $$x_2=b\left( 1-\frac{z}{h}\right) .$$

Comment: I need to back up, I don't understand how you are getting a and b. What is 1 - z/h?

Comment: What is z? I don't see it in the graph

Comment: @user84004  $z$ is the distance from the generic cross-section to the horizontal plane. It varies from $z=0$ to $z=h$. It is also the variable of integration.

Comment: Alright and why is it 1 - z/h?

Comment: @user84004 See the new sketch. I added one of the vertical triangles on the bottom.

Comment: I see that now, this seems like an immensely complicated problem. I will try and do it from the start with your graph.

Comment: Going through thisI don't quite understand how you are integrating with respect to z but you also have variable h. What is happening?

Comment: @user84004  I used the "parameter" $h$ (the height of the cone)  to find a general formula in terms of $a,b,h$. But I could have integrated from $z=0$  to $z=12$ instead, because in your case the height of the cone is $12$.

Comment: But when you find the integral you are left with variables oh h, where did z go?

Comment: The variable $z$ was used in the definite integral 
$$
V =\int_{0}^{h}A(z)\, dz=\int_{0}^{h}\pi ab\left( 1-\frac{z}{h}\right) ^{2}dz=\pi ab\left( h-h+\frac{h}{3}\right) =\frac{h}{3}\pi ab,
$$
The result does not depend on $z$, because I evaluated a definite integral. And I have written "Let $h$ be the height of the cone", which you say is $12$. So I could have computed
$$
V =\int_{0}^{12}A(z)\, dz=\int_{0}^{12}\pi ab\left( 1-\frac{z}{12}\right) ^{2}dz=\pi ab\left( 12-12+\frac{12}{3}\right) =4\pi ab.
$$

Comment: Thank you that makes sense.

Comment: @user84004 You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Assume the cone is tip up. By similarity, the area of horizontal cross-section at distance $w$ **down** from the apex of the cone is 
$$\left(\frac{w}{12}  \right)^2 (\pi ab).$$
Integrate, $w=0$ to $12$.

Better, imagine that the cone is tip down, with tip at the origin. Then the area of cross-section a distance $z$ up from the $x$=$y$ plane is $(z/12)^2(\pi ab)$. For the volume, integrate from $z=0$ to $z=12$.

If you prefer (I don't) you can have the cone in conventional position, and measure distance up from the $x$-$y$ plane.  Then the area of cross-section at distance $z$ above the $x$-$y$ plane is $\left(  \frac{12-z}{12}\right)^2 (\pi ab)$.

**Added:** For the integration, we want 
$$\int_0^{12} (\pi ab)\frac{w^2}{12^2}\,dw.$$
Calculation gives $(\pi ab)\frac{(12)^3}{3\cdot 12^2}$.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fit with what I know and with what Zeev linked: the volume is one third of the base's area times the height, and in this case it is $$\frac{12\pi ab}3=4\pi ab\;...$$

Comment: I don't understand where w/12 comes from and why it is squared.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Note that I had written **Integrate** $w=0$ to $12$. I just took care of the geometry.

Comment: @user84004: By similarity, the cross-section $w$ down from the tip is **similar** to the base of the cone, but shrunk by a factor $w/12$. So its **area** is shrunk by a factor $(w/12)^2$.

Comment: I don't get it then, @AndréNicolas: integrate... *wrt what?*

Comment: With respect to $w$. I added a couple of lines at the end.

Comment: I don't understand where the w formula is from though and why you are squaring it. I understand that the idea of a ratio is what gives w/12 but why suqare that?

Comment: When you scale the **linear** dimensions of an object by the scaling factor $r$, then the **area** is scaled by the factor $r^2$. For example, halfway along, the area of cross-section of the ellipse is $(1/2)^2$ times the area of the big ellipse at the base.

Comment: The scaling factor r is the radius of the ellipse we are taking as a cross section?

Comment: An ellipse has two radii, but let's use the word loosely. The scaling factor is the **ratio** of the radius of the ellipse of cross-section and the radius of the ellipse which which is the base. So as I mentioned earlier, if we take the cross-section halfway, the ellipse of cross-section has radius half the base ellipse, so the scaling factor is $1/2$, or maybe more clearly $6/12$. There is now a nice answer with picture that explains everything in detail.

Comment: I am having trouble visualizing this problem since it is the inverse of all the problems I have done so far. Why are we using w?

Comment: You may prefer the choice of variable in the other answer. Or use my suggestion of $z$ with the cone point down, so that the cross-section grows as $z$ goes from $0$ to $12$.